# Asp.net app on IIS 8.5 subdomain redirection

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on some app in asp.net mvc5. I have problems with redirection.
I'm using `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("www.google.com");` but the problem is that when I deploy on IIS i have web page on subdomain like `somedomain.com/MyApp` so when I use `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("www.google.com");` it creates link like `somedomain.com/www.google.com`so this is where the problem is. I don't now how to get rid of that subdomain ?

David

Comment: add `http://` to the google url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to qualify the protocol you are using, otherwise your addresss tring will be treated as a relative path.

For example:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("https://www.google.com")
```